# Looking for a REST API with template based fake data (NodeJS + key-value store)

Tags: node.js, rest, fixtures

I want to be able to write a config like this...

```
{
    'collection' : 'payments',
    'rows'     : 100,
    'template' : {
        "id"            : "1...100000",
        "status"        : ["None", "SentToPayer", "Overdue", "Completed"],
        "amount"        : ["100","200","500"]
    }
}
```

...and it would create a key-value pair collection in a key-value store (maybe MongoDB) with 100 rows like this:

```
{
    "id": "80494",
    "status": "None",
    "amount": "200"
}
```

And the data would be fully accessible and editable trough a REST API.

`GET http://server/payments/80494` would likely get me the node above.

I am pretty sure I've seen something like this before, but I'm not able to find it right now. Does anyone know something that gives me what I want?

Comment: It's a script that should be easily writtable; have you tried doing it yourself?

Comment: @NickMitchinson Right now I'm using a fork of datafixture.js which does half the job - it generates static json files. https://github.com/janjarfalk/datafixture.js

But, I'm still fairly sure that someone has already solved my problem. No point in inventing the wheel again.

Comment: I agree with not reinventing the wheel, however this is a rather simple problem involving a loop which randomly generates 3 values from sets and inserts them. You don't want to spend more time trying to find the wheel than it would take you to reinvent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating my own thingy.

This one puts data in an MongoDB database.
https://github.com/janjarfalk/datafixture.js

This one expose it.
https://github.com/tdegrunt/mongodb-rest

Answer (score 0):

You can try [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) to fake a REST API on the server side, or [FakeRest](https://github.com/marmelab/FakeRest) to fake a REST API on the client side.